# How to click website submit button on third party website

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to click a website submit button using my c# window application

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"/></p></div>
```

https://www.devpundit.com/contact/   - check this page to see the submit button
It seems like it is calling ajax or javascript call to submit the button.
now how to do this.

I have tried the below 2 option but not working

```
webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("wpcf7-submit").InvokeMember("click");
HTMLInputElement submit = (HTMLInputElement)pass.all.item("wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit", 0);
```

Comment: Is this code related to WinForms' WebBrowser Control? Are you using `MSHTML` (because of `HTMLInputElement`)?

Comment: @Jimi I am using .net winform application and web browser control, Yes I am using MSHTML , Any idea how to click this button in winform

Comment: Yes, I do. In your `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event, add: `var browser = sender as WebBrowser; if (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return; var element = browser.Document.All.OfType<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(elm => elm.GetAttribute("className").Equals("wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit")); element?.InvokeMember("click");`. Of course you have to fill the Form's input elements for the submission to actually work.

Answer (score 1):

First - you are telling the computer to grab the button by its ID, but instead of using the ID, you are putting the class-name where the ID goes. I inspected the element on that page and did not see an "ID" for that element. So let's use what the website gave us.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp
This will give you a list of all the elements that share that class. So instead of

```
webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("wpcf7-submit").InvokeMember("click");
```

please try

Edit: So it turns out there is no GetElementsByClassName in the C# WebBrowser. Another approach instead would be recognizing that the button has a value of "send". The "value" is an attribute, and can be accessed in C#.
[image: inspectedElement]

You can run a for-loop through the  elements in the page and check which input elements have the value "send". It's a bit crude, but it should work.

```
//Create list of HtmlElement objects
        //Populate list with all elements with tag name 'input'
        HtmlElementCollection elementList = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        //loop through the items in elementList, match the one with value set to 'send'
        foreach (HtmlElement currentElement in elementList)
        {
            if (currentElement.GetAttribute("value") == "Send")
            {
                currentElement.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry i can not  see this property GetElementsByClassName i can only see GetElementsByTagName but this doesnt work. I am using .net winform application

Comment: @PrernaPuri you are correct, my apologies. I've edited my code. The new code worked for me.